# How to use multiple States in Dash callback?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I want to use multiple states in one callback. I didnt get it to work so I checked the below example [from the documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks) in which multiple states are used in a callback. Yet, when I run this code I get the error:

**The input argument `submit-button-state.n_clicks` must be a list or tuple of
`dash.dependencies.Input`s**

Two questions:

- Did something change and is the documentation outdated? (which seems unlikely as they have excellent documentation)
- How do I get this to work?

```html
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id='input-1-state', type='text', value='Montréal'),
    dcc.Input(id='input-2-state', type='text', value='Canada'),
    html.Button(id='submit-button-state', n_clicks=0, children='Submit'),
    html.Div(id='output-state')
])


@app.callback(Output('output-state', 'children'),
              Input('submit-button-state', 'n_clicks'),
              State('input-1-state', 'value'),
              State('input-2-state', 'value'))
def update_output(n_clicks, input1, input2):
    return u'''
        The Button has been pressed {} times,
        Input 1 is "{}",
        and Input 2 is "{}"
    '''.format(n_clicks, input1, input2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question works – in recent versions of Dash, the current version being 1.20.0.

The requirement to have all `Output`, `Input` and `State` arguments of `@app.callback` in three seperate lists (as suggested in the answer by Ger) was removed in August 2020 in version 1.15.0 (see [release notes](https://github.com/plotly/dash/releases/tag/v1.15.0)). As seen by the examples in the documentation, doing so is not recommended anymore. If at all possible, update your Dash version instead of switching to the old style.

Comment: it would help to add example

Answer (score 0):

It is as straight forward as the error suggests. I already tried it some ties, but probably I made a typo somewhere.

The solution is to put the inputs, outputs and states all in a seperate list.

```html
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id='input-1-state', type='text', value='Montréal'),
    dcc.Input(id='input-2-state', type='text', value='Canada'),
    html.Button(id='submit-button-state', n_clicks=0, children='Submit'),
    html.Div(id='output-state')
])


@app.callback([Output('output-state', 'children')],
              [Input('submit-button-state', 'n_clicks')],
              [State('input-1-state', 'value'),
              State('input-2-state', 'value')])
def update_output(n_clicks, input1, input2):
    return u'''
        The Button has been pressed {} times,
        Input 1 is "{}",
        and Input 2 is "{}"
    '''.format(n_clicks, input1, input2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```